# Sending form input to a method in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-forms

I've made the following Angular 2 application witch makes use of the numbers API. I would like the user to input a day of the month and a month of the year and when they click the button that data should be sent to the getDayEvent() method which then initiates the service(which works using dummy data). I just need to find a way to send the form data to the method. I've done some research on formcontrols and formgroups but I'm struggling to implement it in my application.

```
@Component({
selector: 'http-test',
template:
  `
<br>
<form id="myForm" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Enter a month</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Enter a day</label></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit">See what happened on this day</button>  
    </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>
<p id="output">{{event}}</p>
`,
providers: [HttpService],
directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class HttpComponent {
event: string;


constructor(private _httpService: HttpService){

}

getDayEvent(month:string, day:string){
this._httpService.getEvent(month, day)
    .subscribe(
        data => this.event = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => alert(error), 
        () => console.log("Finished")
     );
   }
  }
```

And here is my service

```
  @Injectable()
  export class HttpService{
  constructor(private _http: Http){}

  getEvent(month: string, day: string){
    return     
    this._http.get('http://numbersapi.com/'+month+'/'+day+'/date').map(res 
    => res.text());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ngModel in your inputs and click event in your button.

template inputs and button:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="month" type="text">
<input [(ngModel)]="day" type="text">
<button type="submit" (click)="getDayEvent(month,day)">See what happened on this day</button>
```

add the member variables to your class:

```
export class HttpComponent {
event: string;
month: string;
day:string;
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Honestly didn't think is would be that easy. Really appreciate the help, been struggling with this the entire day since I'm really new to Angular 2 and now I can rest in peace.